# What is a scalable way of arranging my firestore db

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

For a system I am going to build with firebase I am wondering what is the most best / scalable way of setting up my database.

I am wondering if I should go with a containerised structure like so :

```
userID
   - contacts
     -- name
     -- id
   - invoices
     -- nr
     -- id
   - clients
```

Or go with a more regular structure like so:

```
     -Invoices
       -- name
       -- id
     -contacts
       -- name
       -- id
     -clients
       -- name
       -- id
```

Comment: The schema you end up adopting will depend a lot on the write/read workloads you expect. What are the access patterns? Can you come up with some reasonable cost projections based on Firestore pricing? All this will inform how you should structure the data.

Comment: NoSQL data modeling is an incredibly broad topic, but it basically boils down to: your model will evolve to cater to the needs of your application. I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/), and watching Todd's excellent video series: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Seconded. Todd needs to realise more of those!

Comment: Cheers guys, and thanks for the links Frank. Watching the series atm.